# Save jasmin spec report to variable or file

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

how to save **JASMIN-SPEC-REPORTER** the test result in the variable or file, , which will later be sent to slack after test?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/tree/master/examples/protractor. Add it to your config:

```
let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
   // your config here ...

   onPrepare: function () {
     jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true
  }
}));
}
}
```

Or you can check out a very cool reporer: https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter. It will take screen shorts and generate your test result to a html file.

Comment: I have this specification, but questions is: How I forward this report  to slack? 

Currently, i get same message on slack when my test pass or not passed..